# how can i know that mongoose document matches filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filter

i want to check mongoose document(D) matches filter(F)

i tried this in latest version of node.js, mongoose, mongodb

i tried to solve this by find all of documents(D_List) that matches filter and check D_List includes D, but this is very ineffecient. is there any function for this?

```
// for Example
let user=await User.findOne({name:'asdf'}); // D
let filter={email:{$regex:'^.*com$'},age:{$gt:10}} // F

console.log(isMatch(user,filter)) // true

function isMatch(user,filter){
    let users=await User.find(filter,{_id:1}); // D_List
    return users.indexOf({_id:user._id})!==-1
}
```

i want to solve this with short and efficiently

Comment: You already have the user in the first line. Couldn't you just check the email and age on that user object?

Comment: this is just for example. i want to check with my own parameter..

Comment: Maybe you can provide the full example for what you're trying to accomplish?  From what you've shown so far, it's hard to understand the context around what you're trying to do and why you need to make a second request to the database.